# Firefox goes to not responding state when a huge javascript is executing

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt

I have a GWT application, which on running in Firefox, makes it go to Not Responding state often.

I tried making the **dom.max_script_run_time** and **dom.max_chrome_script_run** time to **0** in **about:config** page, to allow Firefox to run javascript forever.
Even then the browser goes to Not Responding state.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If the job you're doing is too big for a single script run without locking up the browser, you'll need to break the job up somehow.  Without details on the job you're doing I can only provide general ideas.

The first option, as Teemu describes, is web workers, which are great because they use a separate thread for execution so can really speed up your page.  Unfortunately web workers are designed for data processing, not so much data display, so they don't have dom access, so if the thing you're trying to do is writing a lot of dom objects this might not be the right solution.  Also it's a relatively new technology so browser support can be an issue.

A slightly lower tech solution I've used in the past is an iterator class, which you pass a big array and a function to process, and it uses settimeout to break up the execution into chunks without overloading the browser.  Some sample code below:

```
var Iterator = function( items, callback, complete )
{
    this.items = items;
    this.itemCount = this.items.length;
    this.currentItem = 0;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.completeFunction = complete || function(){};
    this.interval = 50;
    this.started = false;
    this.ajax = false;

    this.start = function()
    {
        if( this.started ) return false;

        var _this = this;
        if( this.itemCount < 1 )
        {
            this.complete();
        }
        else
        {
            this.started = true;
            this.timeout = setTimeout( function(){ _this.progress(); }, _this.interval );
        }
    };

    this.addItem = function( item )
    {
        this.items.push( item );
        this.itemCount = this.items.length;
    }

    this.clearItems = function()
    {
        this.items = [];
        this.itemCount = 0;
        this.currentItem = 0;
        this.started = false;
    }

    this.progress = function()
    {
        this.currentItem++;

        var item = this.items[ this.currentItem - 1 ];

        if( ! this.ajax )
        {
            this.callback( item, this.currentItem, this.itemCount );
            this.next();
        }
        else
        {
            this.callback( item, this );
        }
    };

    this.next = function()
    {
        var _this = this;

        if( this.currentItem >= this.itemCount )
        {
            this.complete();
        }
        else
        {
            this.timeout = setTimeout( function(){ _this.progress(); }, this.interval );
        }
    }

    this.complete = function()
    {
        this.completeFunction();
        this.clearItems();
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
var it = new Iterator( 
    // items to process
    [1,2,3,4,5], 
    // processing function
    function( item, currentItem, totalItems ){
        // process the item
        // write the item to the DOM
        // perhaps show a progress bar?
    }, 
    // complete function
    function(){
        // display completed message
        // perhaps hide the progress bar?
    }
);
it.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for an infinite loop in your code. These days it's very unlikely that you can hang a browser by giving it too much code to process.

Add a GWT.log() statements inside your loops to check which one is causing a problem, and then run your app in a DevMode.